# How do I render a content feed into multiple columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, renderpartial

I am new to programming, just completed RailsTutorial and now am trying to build a Pinterest-type site using Rails.

I'd like for the main site to display items through multiple columns and in an infinite loop like:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

. . . . .

I've got the layout that I'd like, but don't know how to break the content feed into the multiple divs.

home.html.erb (I know this is wrong)

```
<% if signed_in? %>

  <div id="container" summary="For signed-in users">
    <div class="news-column1"><%= render 'shared/feed' %></div>
    <div class="news-column2"><%= render 'shared/feed' %></div>
    <div class="news-column3"><%= render 'shared/feed' %></div>
    <div class="news-column4"><%= render 'shared/feed' %></div>
    <div class="news-column5"><%= render 'shared/feed' %></div>
<% else %>
...
<% end %>
```

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

_feed_item.html.erb

```
<div class="news">
    <div class="comments">
        <%= wrap(feed_item.content) %>
    </div>
    <div class="stats">
        #Likes, #Comments, #Repins
    </div>
    <div class="points">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </div>
</div>
<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
  <div>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, :method => :delete,
                                     :confirm => "You sure?",
                                     :title => feed_item.content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan Bates has shown you how to do this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of):

as a summary here is the code:

```
<table>
<% @tasks.in_groups_of(5, false) do |row_tasks| %>
  <tr>
    <% for task in row_tasks %>
      <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me nicely:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% @buildings.each do |building| %>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= building.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```